# Is there any chance to reassign an IP address assigned to a city to another city/region

Tags: networking, ipv4

Is there any chance to assign an IP address that previously assigned to another system in another city. Or it's fixed for a specific region/city.

Suppose my current ISP assigned `106.52.214.255`. When I reboot my modem, they will assign another address. What happen to `106.52.214.255`, are they going to assign this address to one in another city/region or to one in same region?

I have look up table containing City-IP address mapping. If IP is location specific to city, then only I can use that table for location mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance to assign an IP address that previously assigned to another system in another city. Or it's fixed for a specific region/city.

Under most circumstances, IP addresses tend to remain within the same city.  This is just because most service providers don't build subnets which span cities; there isn't any rule that says subnets cannot span cities though.

> Suppose my current ISP assigned 106.52.214.255. When I reboot my modem, they will assign an another address. Then what happen to 106.52.214.255, are they going to assign this address to one in another city/region or to one in same region.

If your ISP reassigns 106.52.214.255, then they will most-likely reassign it within the same city.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to publicly route-able addresses, then yes. If you have an allocation of IP addresses that have been assigned to you by a registrar and that allocation is an ISP type allocation. You could re-sell or re-distribute an entire allocation or subnet of an allocation. Provided that you fill out the proper forms and provide them to your registrar.

If you are referring to publicly route-able addresses that you would like to utilize at another campus (municipality) that is operated by the owner of the allocation, you can redistribute them a border routers BGP session. You will just want to ensure that you are not distributing them in two separate locations which can cause routing issues.

I'm making an assumption about what you were referring to, because your question is pretty vague. I'd consider rephrasing the question and making it a bit more specific.

Hope this helps.